# How can I import two libraries in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I import bash and expect in the same script? I've tried the following example but it's not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect
```

Both cannot be imported at the same time, only bash works.

Answer (score 7):

There is some severe misunderstanding and/or misconception here.
`#!` aka she-bang does not *import* any library.
This simply indicates the OS which interpreter should be used to run the script.

For example if your script `foo` looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
```

you can simply (assuming you set the executable permission on the script)

```
./foo
```

but if you omit the first line, you have to

```
/bin/bash ./foo
```

`bash` and `expect` are (very) distinct interpreted language, and hence you have to decide which language you want to use, and then use the appropriate interpreter.

Having two interpreter for the same script is a plain non-sense.

Answer (score 1):

Both bash and expect cannot be used in the same script. It can be done like this.

```html
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
 

 

spawn.....  #actual code need to be run by using bash
 
expect "Enter password for store:"
 
send -- "password\r"
 
expect "Enter password:"
 
send -- "password\r"
 

expect eof
```

This code was used to run a jar file which requires a password. So by running this script file by using expect library it could be done. This script will enter the password automatically.For running the jar file it needed the sh library.